# .jar files cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.2)

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I am trying to run a helloworld example of scalatra (http://www.smartjava.org/content/tutorial-getting-started-scala-and-scalatra-part-ii) in eclipse and when I import the project in eclipse I get the error popup

[image: eclipse error]

I am using kepler with 2.10 scala version

Note: I clicked on Yes but now it gives me cross compilation errors which are following

1. grizzled-slf4j_2.9.2-0.6.9.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.2).
2. lift-json_2.9.1-2.4.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.1).
3. rl_2.9.2-0.3.2.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.2).
4. specs2_2.9.2-1.12.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.2).
5. specs2-scalaz-core_2.9.2-6.0.1.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.2).

Comment: Not an error,  click Yes. Inform scaltara team about eclipse complication, so that they update tutorial or escalate to sbt.

Comment: Even after I say yes it gives me an error in the console 
Unable to find a scala library. Please add the scala container or a scala library jar to the build path.

Comment: I know this is not the answer your looking for, but I strongly suggest using SBT with Intellij for Scala.  It is the recommended build tool and IDE respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of the Scala IDE does not support Scala 2.9, unfortunately. You need to update your project. If you are using Sbt for your test project, it should be enough to set your scala version to `2.10.3` and export to eclipse (using [sbt-eclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse). Depending on your Eclipse settings, you might need to Refresh the workspace.